# What's happening when we use mail() in PHP?

Tags: php, email

```
<?php
mail("joecool@example.com", "My Subject", "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3");
?>
```

We don't need to specify the `email/password/mail server address && port`,but it can be sent .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the email/password/mail server address/port is defined in your PHP.ini file.

Comment: mysql.default_user or something along those lines.

Comment: See this page: http://us.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php (Yeah, that mysql thing was a brain fart)

Answer (score 3):

On *nix [`sendmail(8)`](http://ibm5.ma.utexas.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sendmail+8) is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's stored in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `mail()` does not support SMTP authentication.  If you need SMTP authentication check out http://pear.php.net/package/Mail